Accessing a VHD to restore files via SMB
We create hourly backups of Windows servers and the backups disks are accessible as VHDs.
If I need to restore a VM I can:
a) shutdown the production VM
b) spin up a new VM from the backup VHD.
If I only need to restore some files/folders I have a problem and am unsure of how best to solve it.
I am unable to spin up a new VM from the backup VHD as it will conflict with the production VM. If I am remove the NIC and spin up the VM from backup it will not conflict however the VM will be inaccessible on the LAN.
I am wondering if a solution would be a basic Linux VM (with GUI) to:

Start up
Attach the disk from the backup containing the files I wish to restore
Share the disk via SMB on the LAN
Access the SMB share from the production VM and copy the files/folders

Is there a better way?

Are you using a backup application? That is what determines the steps/procedure for restoration. Just because you copied a file(s) doesn't mean that is a backup or can be restored.

Yes, backup application however it does not have file/folder restore functionality. Just VM restore.

Yes, you can attach the VHD file to any other Virtual Machine or any Windows 10/11 physical machine and browse the files.

I was looking for a simple Linux VM that I could add the disk via a GUI and share via SMB

You can do whatever you want with the VHD file. Attach it it a VM or attach it to a physical computer.

Looking to see if there is a particular Linux Distro specifically suited to this task. Attaching VHDs and sharing via SMB. Nas?
